# red is a color creating anger

Tags: present-participles, participle-clauses

*(a) Red is a color creating anger.*

*(b) Red is a color which creates anger*

The first sentence above is supposed to be grammatically incorrect. Could you clarify what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing grammatically wrong with the sentence, but it's hard to imagine circumstances where it would be called for.

On the other hand, it's also hard to imagine circumstances where the other would be called for, either, and for the same reason: why would anybody ever have to predicate that *red* is a color?

Ordinarily we'd just say "Red creates anger" (all the time) or "Red is creating anger" (at this moment, among this particular population).

I'd guess that this pair of sentences is a grammar-book exercise, whose immediate point is that **we don't ordinarily use present participle clauses to define permanent properties**.

Comment: Oh! Where's your last sentence gone?

Comment: @Araucaria I decided I'd already said it, and it didn't need rubbing in.